Restart poem numbering with each chapter
Using \PoemTitle in the memoir class results in continuous numbering of the poems across the entire book.  I would like to restart the numbering in each chapter.  Is this possible?
Here's an mwe:

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First chapter}
\PoemTitle{This should be numbered `1'}

\PoemTitle{This should be numbered `2'}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\PoemTitle{This should again be numbered `1'}

\end{document}


Hm, your code can’t compile …

Try \counterwithin*{poem}{chapter}

@MS-SPO, what errors are you getting?  I can successfully compile the mwe.

Copy your posted code into a fresh file and see for yourself ;-) // No class, no package ...
